# Cache react-router route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4, react-router-redux

I have the following code:

```
<View>
  <Header />
  <List />
</View>
```

If the user clicks on an edit button in a list item, `react-router` changes the page from `/list` to `/list/{itemId}`. This is a new page. After the user filled in some information and clicks on save, `react-router` changes back to `/list`. Now the full `/list`-page is rerendered!

Is there a way to cache a page, so `react` can detect the changes and rerender only them instead of the full page again?

It should also be possible to render the page directly (not over `/list` -> `/list/{itemId}`) so no `modal` solution I think.

I'm using `react-router-redux v5.0.0-alpha.9` so the solution should be compatible with it. It should also be compatible with `react-native` and `react-dom`.

Comment: This isn't a feature supported by react-router directly, but the `<Route>` component does have a `render` prop that you could use to show/hide the component rather than the default behavior of unmounting it when navigating to a new route. See https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4888. I'm not sure what timdorr meant by "that will have unintended side effects most likely" but I imagine that in cases like this it should be fine (unless you're doing it all over the place).

Answer (score 4):

## If you are working with `react-router`

Component can not be cached while going forward or back which lead to **losing data and interaction** while using `Route`

Component would be unmounted when Route was unmatched

After reading source code of Route we found that using children prop as a function could help to control rendering behavior.

**Hiding instead of Removing** would fix this issue.

I am already fixed it with my tools [react-router-cache-route](https://github.com/CJY0208/react-router-cache-route)

### Usage

Replace `<Route>` with `<CacheRoute>`

Replace `<Switch>` with `<CacheSwitch>`

---

## If you want real `<KeepAlive />` for `React`

I have my implementation [react-activation](https://github.com/CJY0208/react-activation)

[Online Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-beaver-solkt)

### Usage

```
import KeepAlive, { AliveScope } from 'react-activation'

function App() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(true)

  return (
    <AliveScope>
      <button onClick={() => setShow(show => !show)}>Toggle</button>
      {show && (
        <KeepAlive>
          <Test />
        </KeepAlive>
      )}
    </AliveScope>
  )
}
```

[image]

The implementation principle is easy to say.

Because `React` will unload components that are in the intrinsic component hierarchy, we need to extract the components in `<KeepAlive>`, that is, their `children` props, and render them into a component that will not be unloaded.

Answer (score 2):

Got into same problem recently and my initial nudge was to use something like `react-router-cache-route` or another package.

But main disadvantage of third-party packages is that they are usually slow to support new react-router versions and source code seemed to me overly complex for this problem.

So I researched further and stumbled on [this suggestion](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/12039#issuecomment-359801971) from Dan Abramov and ended up with solution like this:

```
function App() {
  const itemId = useParams<{ itemId: string }>();

  return (
    <Switch>
       ...
       <Route
          exact
          path={['some-list-route', 'some-list-route/:itemId']}
       >
          <List style={itemId ? { display: 'none' } : undefined} />
          {itemId && <ListItem />}
       </Route>
       ...
    </Switch>
  )
}
```

We keep both `list` and `item` routes under single Route component to have control over their mounting behaviour. When we get `item` route — we hide our `<List />` (but it stays mounted, "kept-alive") and conditionally mount `<ListItem />`.

We can also pass `itemId` to `<List />` as a prop, if we need more control, like conditionally trigger data fetching only for `list` route.